# How to have an example for a file in request or response in Swagger UI - Open API 3?

Tags: mime-types, swagger-ui, openapi, swagger-editor

If we have a MIME type such as application/vnd.excel or application/pdf then how can we give a example in schema in either request body or response?

Like for string, integer we can give example, is there a way for such excel files - Defining what should be the columns in Excel file?